# Firebase firestore security rules

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Help solve firestore rules configuration problem

I'm recording an array in the firestore like this.

```
self.db.collection("events").document(EventIdent).updateData([
  "GiftsListSelected.\(Uphone!)": FieldValue.arrayUnion([GiftIdent])
```

Where's Uphone - phoneNumber from FirebaseAuth

In the rules, I check the record.

```
allow write: if (('GiftsListSelected.' + request.auth.token.phone_number) in request.writeFields)
```

Please help me write me a rule to also test...

1. so that the size of array in document 'GiftsListSelected.' + request.auth.token.phone_number' after adding thus request is no larger than 10.
2. whatever GiftIdent does not repeat itself in GiftsListSelected.

Struct firestore

[image]

Comment: This really isn't a code writing service - can you update your question to show us what you're attempted for 1 and 2? Once we get a better understanding of the issue, we can try to help.